# Disable CKEditor Link "browse server" button

Tags: ckeditor

Looking for a very simple way to disable/remove the CKEditor "browse server" button when using the Link toolbar button.

Answer (score 3):

All you need to do is ensure that [`filebrowserBrowseUrl`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-filebrowserBrowseUrl) config property is set to an empty string. Like so:

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
    filebrowserBrowseUrl: ''
} );
```

Note that this will remove the Browse Server button when inserting an image as well. To remedy this issue you can set filebrowserBrowseUrl to '' and then set filebrowserImageBrowseUrl to the url of your file/image browser.

Comment: Thank you Marek for your reply!  I have updated the the code, as follows where you can see the string has been added and I still receive the link browser server button.

    <script>
 CKEDITOR.replace( 'Content', {
 customConfig: '../../../ckeditor/configFULL.js',
            height:['400px'],
 filebrowserBrowseUrl: '',
 filebrowserWindowWidth: '600',
 filebrowserWindowHeight: '500',
        filebrowserBrowseUrl: '../../../ckeditor/ckfinder/ckfinder.html',
 filebrowserUploadUrl: '../../../ckeditor/ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Images',
      } );
</script>

Comment: You can see that you have specified the `filebrowserBrowseUrl` property twice... then it's overriden. It should have been (see https://gist.github.com/mlewand/47bae22556888f3eeff5):

    CKEDITOR.replace('Content', {
        customConfig: '../../../ckeditor/configFULL.js',
        height: ['400px'],
        filebrowserBrowseUrl: '',
        filebrowserWindowWidth: '600',
        filebrowserWindowHeight: '500',
        filebrowserUploadUrl: '../../../ckeditor/ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload‌​&type=Images',
    });

Comment: Yes, I see. Ok that disables the browser server button for links and images both.  I'm looking for a way to disable it only for links.  Do you know of such?

Comment: That's a different question.

Answer (score 2):

Just replace `filebrowserBrowseUrl` with `filebrowserImageBrowseUrl`, and you will only see the "browser button" in the Image pop-up dialog.

Please refer to the document: http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-filebrowserBrowseUrl